# how to make a automatic php function that should check that if any kind of data is submitted if yes then show the posted data

Tags: javascript, php

i have a php file hosted on the url `https://akshayshrivastav.me/index.php`

What i am doing is keeping this url open on the mozilla browser.

What i am doing is i am send a post request from chrome browser to that url now what happens is i have this following code

```
<?php
    if($_POST)
        {
            print_r($_POST);   
        }
    else
        {
            echo "No Request Received! Please Check the Request You Are Trying To Make!";
        }
?>
```

The above code will run on chrome browser as when the form f=data is posted to this url the page will show the posted contents.

but in mozilla browser what i want is even if the data is submitted through chrome browser it should dynamically refresh the page in mozzila browser whenever a post or get request is made to that following url and show the posted values.

Please help in logic.

Comment: 1 of the suggestions (and probably not the best one) is that you can try to combine AJAX with PHP: Upon getting `POST`, save in database a value and then in Firefox add `setInterval()` with Ajax request to check when you got changes in DB. When you see that, execute something from JavaScript to update the page content.

Comment: ok means is there any demo i just want it to set for 5 mins

Comment: I can write an example if you're OK with that. But not at the moment, later.

Comment: sure that would be perfect!

Comment: if you dont want pure php solution you might set sleep interval with js and check db status and update your page according to it which is basically what social media messengers doing. if you want php solution you might set a cron job that checks db and updates pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using code for table:

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `time` int(10) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

I have written everything in 1 file but you should separate at least form. Short version: sending `POST` request from jQuery every X seconds/minutes and checking return value. If we get X value, we reload the page, otherwise, continue sending requests.

I have commented some lines to better understand why I wrote like that. It's probably not perfect (I might have missed something) but in general it's working (tested):

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'test_database');

/* Must connect to database first, otherwise it's no use */
if ($db->connect_errno) {
    exit('Connection failed because: '.$db->connect_error);
}

/* Check if we received $_POST from jQuery script */
if (isset($_POST['lastRow'])) {
    $query = $db->query('SELECT id FROM items ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1');
    $result = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    if (is_null($result)) {
        $lastRow = 0;
    } else {
        $lastRow = $result['id'];
    }

    /* Return 1 if DB was changed, otherwise, return 0 */
    if ($_POST['lastRow'] != $lastRow) {
        echo 1;
    } else {
        echo 0;
    }

    /* We don't need to print entire HTML code */
    exit;
}

/* Add new item through $_POST */
if (!empty($_POST['item_name'])) {
    $item = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['item_name']);
    $query = $db->query('INSERT INTO items (name, time) VALUES("'.$item.'", '.time().')');

    if ($query) {
        echo 'Item successfully added!<br>';
    } else {
        echo 'Item was not successfully added because: '.$db->error.'<br>';
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>Page with items list</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$query = $db->query('SELECT id FROM items ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1');
$result = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

/* If table is empty, give 0 rows, otherwise, take last ID */
if (is_null($result)) {
    $lastRow = 0;
} else {
    $lastRow = $result['id'];
}
?>

<!-- FORM AREA -->
<div id="form_div" class="col-lg-2 form-group">
    <form action="" method="post">
        <label for="item_name">Item name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="item_name" name="item_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter item name">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Insert">
    </form>
</div>

<!-- ROW PRINTING AREA -->
<div id="table_div" class="col-log-12">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Creation time</th>
        </tr>
    <?php
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM items");

    while ($result = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $result['id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo date('Y-m-d', $result['time']); ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </table>
</div>

<!-- Launching script when document is loaded -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('ready', function(e) {
    function checkData() {
        /* Sending POST HTTP request */
        $.post('consi.php', { lastRow: <?php echo $lastRow; ?> }, function(data) {
            if (data == 1) {
                /* OK, last row was changed, so just reload the page to see new results */
                window.location.href = window.location.href;
            }
        });     
    }

    /* 1000 -> 1 second */
    setInterval(checkData, 5000);
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sure definetely :D

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code in your index.php file

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
```

where value 30 is time.

Comment: Not quite enough because it won't tell if request was received.

Comment: You can try it in condition if(!empty($_POST['some_varibale])) {
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
}